# Clean public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am have a ruby web app and after cleaning the database, I would like to clean the public folder that contains images that users created and that are under my `/public/user_images`.  Is there a `Rake command` I can use for this purpose?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure the `rake tmp:clear` will clean the public images, but it should clean temporary and asset files under public.

Comment: Why don't you simply run ``rm -r public/user_images`` ?

Comment: @Intrepidd: I did not dare to run the rm -r as I was afraid it would mess the app indexing of files but perhaps you right, I could give it a try

Comment: If all that's in this directory is the images you want to remove, there's no risk.

Comment: What about creating a new rake task using intrepidds' suggestion.

Comment: rake assets:clean this clean all compiled assets, If you have any, also hard delete of directory may remove useful data also.

Comment: @Intrepidd I did delete the content and it work. did not create any mess. Many thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command

```
rm -r /public/user_images
```